# C# MS Project Interop - Get Resource's Working Time

Tags: c#, interop, ms-project

In MS Project I can go the resource sheet, then right click on a resource, go the the Resource Information dialog, then click "Change Working Time..." and enter holidays, sick leave or other absences for that resource.  I'd like to access the same information programatically from C#.

I have the Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project object loaded in memory and I can access tasks and other properties.  From the Project object I can access the Resource property (type Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Resource) but don't know where in that type to find a resource's working times.

I'm using VS2008 with MS Project 2007.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My (out of date) understanding of MS Project is that the working time for a resource is set in a calendar.  After a quick Google (and Bing!), it looks that [something like this is what you're after.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178439%28v=office.12%29.aspx)